# Dynamic LINQ Select method "selector" argument

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I´m struggling with Dynamic LINQ. 
Given an IQueryable List ( var queryable MyList.AsQueryable ) my linq statement would be

```
        var queryable = plist.AsQueryable();
        query =  from People p in queryable
                    .Where<People>( "whereclause" )
                .Select( p );
```

The compiler tells "The name 'p' does not exist in the current context" regarding the .Select( p ) line.

What could I do if I want to get the complete instance of People? 
I know the Select extension method of Dynamic.cs

```
public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, string selector, params object[] values)
```

expects a string argument for a "selector", but cannot figure what to set it to simply get the entire instance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The correct form will be `.Select( p => p )`, but it's redundant as @mjwills said

Comment: I was actually wrong earlier - it should instead by `select p`. I have edited the question (changed the indentation) to make it clearer why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are mixing the two ways of using LINQ expressions, you have to use either Lambda expression or SQL-Like expression not a combination of both.

1. Lambda Expression:
   `var result = plist.AsQueryable().Where(x => true).ToList();`

Note: `.Where(x => true)` should contain your filtering logic eg `.Where(p => p.Age > 14 && p.Age < 21)` then you have two choices either to box that object into a list by adding `.ToList();` or to choose which properties you want into your object then you will add `.Select(s=> s.Age).ToList();` this expression will return List assuming you have a property on int Age in your object or you can return a specific object by casting from retrieved values into your new object or receive data in a new anonymous object `.Select(s=> new Person {Age = s.Age}).ToList();` or `.Select(s=> new {newProp = s.Age}).ToList();`

2. SQL Like 
   `var result = from object o in plist // query object
                   where true          // your condition
                   select o;           // selected values`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

```
    var query = from People p in queryable
                    .Where<People>("whereclause")
                select p;
```